Задача о 19 ферзях
На шахматном поле 8х8 нужно расставить 10 черных и 9 белых ферзей, чтобы белые не били черных, а черные белых
Решение в лоб не пойдет, т.к. будет исполняться долго. Подскажите идею решения, которая сократит перебор

Ферзь бьет горизонталь, вертикаль, две диагонали. Этих линий на доске не так много - может, от этого отталкиваться?

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/78727

Идея: расставить девять ферзей так чтобы остались небитыми десять клеток. Это перебирабельно.

Я долго возился с программкой, ни разу не удалось расставить. Я не уверен, что решение есть.

На всякий случай: https://www.bestprog.net/ru/2019/05/01/the-problem-of-n-queens-solution-using-c-2-ru/

Или я где-то ошибся, что очень может быть - типа условие перепутал или на доске не вижу, кто кого бьет... Но проверьте своим глазом. Белые a8, a7,b8,b7.b6,c7,c6,g8,g7. Черные d1,d2,d3,e1,e2,f1,f5,h3,h4,h5. А вот 11, похоже, нереально. Но доказать что-то не выходит.

Нашел уже 8 решений - но это так, скорее везение :) Методом @StanislavVolodarskiy - собственно, первое, что приходит в голову. Все же расставить 9 ферзей можно меньшим числом способов, чем 10 :)

Какие 8, 9 или 10? Надо 19! Вот в этом случае я сильно сомневаюсь в существовании решения. Сам по себе алгоритм вроде как есть.

@FoxFox Забавно, как вы путаете количество найденных решений с количеством ферзей... :( Просто посмотрите одну из найденных мною расстановок и посчитайте, сколько там ферзей всего, и сколько каких...

Извините, не прочёл внимательно.

Зато можно расставить 64 белых ферзей и 0 черных

Есть ещё два решения - 64 черных и ноль тех и тех.

@FoxFox Тогда уж в общем случае есть  36893488147419103231 тривиальных расстановок...

Окончательное решение :)
Всего есть 24 таких решения, но принципиальных - которые не приводятся одно к другому поворотом или какой симметрией - только три.
 9: b1 b2 f2 f3 g1 g2 g3 h1 h2
10: a4 a5 a6 c4 c8 d7 d8 e6 e7 e8

 9: c1 c2 d1 g2 g3 g4 h1 h2 h3
10: a5 a6 a7 b5 b6 e7 e8 f6 f7 f8

 9: c1 c2 c3 d1 d2 g3 g4 h2 h3
10: a6 a7 a8 b5 b6 b7 e7 e8 f7 f8

Полный перебор (который можно было сократить с использованием симметрии, но мне стало лень, просто оставил на ночь считать все 27540584512 вариантов и даже не использовал многопоточность :). Если верить временной отметке файла, решилось часа за 2.5 (скажем точнее - было найдено последнее решение)).

может еще само решение добавить? Код имею ввиду :)

@Grundy Вот не уверен... Когда пишешь для ответа — стараясь сделать его понятным и эффективным, это что-то одно, а если для себя, лишь бы сработало — это что-то совсем другое :) И потом, просили-то на C, а я отработал на C++. Идеологически же — перебираю все перестановки из 9 единиц и 55 нулей (9 ферзей), расставляю на доске и отмечаю клетки под боем. Затем считаю, сколько же осталось свободных клеток; если 10 — вывожу расклад.
